# Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8(update v2 to v3)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss, autoprefixer

I am trying to update tailwindcss v2 to v3(I am using ReactJs). I have installed the latest version of autoprefixer, tailwindcss and postcss.
This is the error:

> ./src/index.css
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css) Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8. Migration guide
> for end-users:
> https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users

These are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.0",
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.11",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-youtube": "^7.13.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

Comment: Have you tried completely removing PostCSS from node_modules and reinstalled?

Comment: @kluvin yes, same problem. I forgot to put the full error:
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users

Answer (score 4):

You're integrating Tailwind with a tool that relies on an older version of PostCSS. You can use this doc https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-8-compatibility-build

If this doesnt work, try this
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using React with Parcel [tailwindcss setup for parcel](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/parcel) - adding the following in .postcssrc did the trick for me..

```js
{
  "plugins": {
    "tailwindcss": {
      "config": "./tailwind.config.js"
    }
  }
}
```